# Can't locate perl module in @inc even though error message says its in @inc

Tags: perl, perl-module, locate

I'm trying to execute a perl script and I've gotten it to work before when I run it in the folder it's located in... ie, the following works.

```
\higherFolder\folder>UpdateTestCasesScript.pl Test.feature Test_Cases.xls
```

Buuuuut when I try to run this script on the command line OUTSIDE of that folder

```
\HigherFolder>folder\UpdateTestCasesScript.pl RealFile.feature folder\Test_Cases.xls
```

I get this weird error:

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm in @INC <@INC contains: Spreadsheet/Parse
Excel.pl C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry
/perl/lib .> at C:...\HigherFolder\folder\UpdateTestCasesScript.pl line 4
```

But if you look at the first few lines of my script... they are the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use lib 'Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm';
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
```

So I have an idea that it may be looking at the wrong @INC somehow, but does anyone have any idea how to fix it??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is usually in `@INC`, making Perl look in the current work directory for modules. It stopped working when you changed the CWD because nothing else in `@INC` allowed it to find the module.

To look for modules in the relative to the directory in which the script is located:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

---

By the way, `use lib 'Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm';` makes no sense whatsoever. The argument should be the directory in which `Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm` is located (more or less).

Answer (score 8):

The argument to `use lib` should be the folder which contains `Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm`, e.g:

```
use lib '/higherFolder/folder';
```